Example of cyclotomic $\mathbb{Z}_{p}$ extension which are not totally ramified
Let $\zeta_{p^n}$ be the $p^n$th power root of unity. Then $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{p^n})$ is an abelian extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ of degree $p^{n-1}(p-1)$. It has an unique sub-extension $\mathbb{Q}_n$ such that $Gal(\mathbb{Q}_n/\mathbb{Q}) \cong \mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}$.
Let $K$ be a number field. Let $e$ be an integer such that $\mathbb{Q}_e\subset K$ but $\mathbb{Q}_{e+1}\not\subset K$. Define $K_n=K\mathbb{Q}_{e+n}$. Then $K=K_0 \subset K_1\subset K_2\subset \cdots K_n\subset K_\infty:=\cup_n K_n$ is the cyclotomic $\mathbb{Z}_p$ extension.
Let $H$ be the Hilbert class field of $K$. Assume $H\cap K_\infty=K_m$ for some integer $m$. Do we always have $m=0$? Could someone give an example when $m\geq 1$?
I know the basics of Iwasawa theory and know that the possible primes rimified inside any $\mathbb{Z}_p$ extension $K_\infty/K$ are primes above $p$. The ramified primes will become totally ramified start from some layer. People often assume that primes ramified in $K_\infty/K$ are totally ramified for simplicity. For the cyclotomic $\mathbb{Z}_p$ extension, could we remove the usual assumption? In other words, is every cyclotomic $\mathbb{Z}_{p}$ extensions $K_\infty^c/K$  totally ramified from the first layer?
